# jQuery - show list after it loads

Tags: jquery, json, load, show

I've made a script, to get child genres from a "parent" genre from a MySQL database, using `getJSON()`. To show the list of child genres, I used `show()` function, but because the list hasn't loaded yet, it will just pop up, and I don't like that. How do I use the `load()` function (or any other that will help my case) to wait until the list is loaded and then use `show()`?

```
function getZvrsti(id){
        $.getJSON('test.php?parent='+id, function(data) {
            var tmpLi;
            $.each(data, function(id, name) {
                tmpLi = $('<li><input type="checkbox" value="'+name['id']+'" id="zvrstId'+name['id']+'" /> <label for="zvrstId"'+name['id']+'">'+name['name']+'</label></li>');
                $(".drugeZvrsti").append(tmpLi);
                tmpLi = "";
            });
        });
    }
```

This is the function, which uses `getJSON`, and here is the snipped where I use `show()`:

```
$(".naprejZvrst").click(function(){
            if(!on2){
                parent = $(this).attr("id");
                getZvrsti(parent);
                $(".drugeZvrsti").load(function(){ //my poor example of load()
                    druga.show(400);
                });
                on2 = true;

            }
            else if(on2){
                druga.hide(400);
                on2 = false;
                $(".drugeZvrsti").html(''); 
            }

        })
```

Class `drugeZvrsti` is the `<ul>` list, where list is shown, `var druga` is a `<div>`, where the whole `<ul>` list is.
NOTE: I've found example of `load()` function, but none explained how to use with a list, most were for images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) which is a shorthand for [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) is per default asynchronous which means that code execution will continue after you've called it.

What you want to do is to show the list in the callback once you've built and appended the list items.

```
// Let's define our local scope variables
var druga = $(".drugeZvrsti"),
    request = false;

function getZvrsti(id) {
    // Save the request to our requests object
    requests[id] = $.getJSON('test.php?parent='+id, function(data) {
        var html = "";
        $.each(data, function(id, name) {
            html += '<li><input type="checkbox" value="'+name['id']+'" id="zvrstId'+name['id']+'" /> <label for="zvrstId"'+name['id']+'">'+name['name']+'</label></li>';
        });
        // Append the list items and then fade in
        druga.append(html).show(400);
        // We no longer have a request going
        request = false;
    });
}

$(".naprejZvrst").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    // Since we don't want multiple requests, abort any existing one
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
        request = false;
    }
    if (druga.is(":hidden")) {
        getZvrsti(id);
    } else {
        // Stop any animations, fade out and
        // use callback to empty the list when its hidden
        druga.stop().hide(400, function(){
            druga.empty();
        });
    }
});
```

You can also note some other changes I've done here, such as:

- Caching the selector for the list since it's used multiple times
- Building the list as a plain string and append it once. This is because DOM manipulation is slow, so a good practice is to keep that down to a minimum.
- Saving the request to a variable so if there's any ongoing request it can be aborted when the list is hidden
- Checking visibility of `druga` with `.is` instead of using the variable `on2`

Comment: Great script! Almost everything works fine now! Only one problem now: if I show druga, hide it and try to show it again, nothing will appear, which is bothering.

Comment: Nevermind that, my script was slightly different, all fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you add a callback function to be executed when `getJSON` has succeeded you can see when it has finished.  Although I've just made `druga` show you'll have to modify this to set a variable which you'll then check in your click event.  It's all in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

```
function successFunction(data) {
  druga.show(400);
}

function getZvrsti(id){
        $.getJSON('test.php?parent='+id, function(data) {
            var tmpLi;
            $.each(data, function(id, name) {
                tmpLi = $('<li><input type="checkbox" value="'+name['id']+'" id="zvrstId'+name['id']+'" /> <label for="zvrstId"'+name['id']+'">'+name['name']+'</label></li>');
                $(".drugeZvrsti").append(tmpLi);
                tmpLi = "";
            });
        }, successFunction(i));
    }
```

Comment: @MarcusEkwall - I haven't tested it, just made it to point the OP in the right direction.  Do you have any feedback on why this won't work?

Comment: You updated your code, but it's still wrong. `$.each` doesn't take a callback. Also, you aren't passing it as an argument but actually the result of it. As you can see there is already a callback, so there's really no need to add a second one, and if you really need to the correct way would be to add a `.done(successFunction)` to the `$.getJSON` call.

Comment: Okay like I said I haven't actually tested it - I can see no mention of `.done()` in the docs.

Comment: @medmondson the [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object that is returned by `$.getJSON` implements the behavior of a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). I suggest the usage of [`.done`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) since `.success` will be [deprecated in 1.7](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9399).

Answer (score 0):

you could use a callback like this:

```
function getZvrsti(id, callback){
    $.getJSON('test.php?parent='+id, callback(data));
}
```

...

```
 getZvrsti(parent, function(data) {
        var tmpLi;

        $.each(data, function(id, name) {
            tmpLi = $('<li><input type="checkbox" value="'+name['id']+'" id="zvrstId'+name['id']+'" /> <label for="zvrstId"'+name['id']+'">'+name['name']+'</label></li>');
            $(".drugeZvrsti").append(tmpLi);
            tmpLi = "";
        });

       druga.show(400);
 });
```

untested code